# Start Android gallery app without specifying or picking image

Tags: android, directory, gallery

How can we start the gallery app in Android without telling it which file to display?

This is because I want to show images in an album/folder.  However, I understand there is no such function.  So, I would like to just start the gallery app.

ACTION_VIEW will always result in an "unsupported file" message, if there is no URI specified, or if MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is specified.  This is bearable, but not desirable, as it tells the user something is wrong with my app.

ACTION_PICK works partially, but the later half is not what I want.  I want the user to choose images, and see the chosen images in the gallery.  The gallery should not return the URI to my app, and expect my app to display it.  There is a reason for this, that is, I want the user to be able to switch from one image to another without returning to my app.  The user should return only after he/she has decided not to view anymore image.

The code that I have tried :

```
        intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType ("image/*");
        startActivity (intent);

        intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                 MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity (intent);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage()

Comment: Further there is no 'the gallery app'.

Comment: Thanks.  But I have no idea what "gallery app" the user has or prefers to use.  So, I have no package name to give to the getLaunchIntentForPackage() method.  The purpose is to let the user see an album/folder in whatever app he/she is comfortable with.  If I cannot specify the album/folder, at least start such an app (and without knowing which app will be started).